# Analyze Websites for Key Words

Tags: api, data, github

I'd like to analyze Github and other websites for the prevelancy of certain key words. How would I go about doing this?

The solution must be able to complete the following:

1. Check for the occurrence of a keyword in a website.
2. Check when a specific keyword was posted.

A good model for this is Google Trends, but specific to websites. I'll be starting this project with Github. Is there a webcrawler or API that can accomplish this?